# Token Based Authentication in Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I've read some article on token based authentication in Asp.Net Core. I'm new to Asp.Net Core and Token based Authentication. Can anyone help me with that? Some code will be helpful for me. I'm using latest version of visual studio community 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent tutorial already written [here](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/)

Also, [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) have a lot of tutorials that show you how to configure identity server (to generate tokens) and how to secure your web api (token based authentication).